# Alternative to firebase login:ci authentication token(service account option does not work)

Tags: firebase, gcloud, firebase-tools

I was using firebase cli "login:ci" command to get a universal firebase token to create firebase projects in google account but that is not the recommended solution anymore. The recommendation is to move to the service account key file going forward. The problem with this solution is, service account is tied to a project. Can someone please tell me how this works? Does this have to be a service account in an organization which has permissions to create projects inside that organization?